# SNMP: Configuring/Enabling SNMPv3 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, snmp

How do I enable SNMP v3 and configure SNMP v3 users and groups in Windows 7?

Comment: @techie007 Thanks. And +1 for noting that it is being deprecated.

Comment: No problem, not really sure why I didn't post it as an answer -- so I did.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't support SNMPv3 inherently; you'll need a 3rd party solution.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379141(VS.85).aspx) (yes I know it doesn't mention 7+ specifically, this is just the most recent MS document I could find. :) ).

SNMP is actually [being depreciated in Windows server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831568.aspx).

3rd Party Solutions:

1. [MG-SOFT](http://www.mg-soft.si/agent.html) - Commercial
2. [SNMP-Informant](http://www.snmp-informant.com/) - Commercial
3. [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/download.html) - Open Source